# How to make VSCode cursor macro instantanious?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm using the [multi-command extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command), and after pasting some text in a macro, I move the cursor around a few times, like the following:

```
{
    "command": "multiCommand.test",
    "interval": 0,
    "sequence":[
        {
            "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
            "args": {"snippet": "some text\n\n"}
        },
        {"command" : "cursorUp"},
        {"command" : "cursorUp"},
        {"command" : "cursorEnd"},
    ]
}
```

Everything ends up correct, but there's a noticeable delay in the cursor executing these commands that I'd like to be instantaneous (e.g. i'd like to not see it go through every step but just end up at the right spot.) Is there some setting I can change, or other command I can use to just instruct the cursor to move to a certain coordinate in the text?

Comment: That is as instantaneous as you are going to get with multi-command.  It is running each of those commands serially awaiting each to finish.  There is a `cursorMove` command which can sometimes help, see the options at https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the field `$0` in your snippet

```
"snippet": "some text$0\n\n"
```

And remove the cursor commands